# for loop in C++

Tags: c++

I'm just a little curious where the extra goes and if there is a better way to not have a loss of accuracy with a for()

```
for(int a = 10; a >= 0; a -= 3)
    cout << a << endl;
```

outputs `10 7 4 1`

So I'm wondering where and why it doesn't keep going as 1 is still greater than 0. I understand the signed aspect that's not there and its an int but what happens to the last 1? I assume its just gone into thin air. So i was wondering if anyone could explain why it does not continue or at least why it outputs `10, 7, 4, 1` 
instead of `10, 7, 4, 1, 1` and how is it possible to make it 
output `10, 7, 4, 1, -2`

Comment: After the last 1,  `a -= 3` produces a `-2`, and since `a >= 0` is now false, the loop no longer runs.

Comment: -2 is less than zero

Comment: 1) "_if there is a better way to not have a loss of accuracy with a for()_" What loss of accuracy? Computer does what you tell it to do, not what you want it to do. 2) "_and how if possible to make it output {10, 7, 4, 1, -2}_" By making `for` condition `for(int a = 10; a >= -2; a -= 3)`, if that's what you intended.

Comment: The loop condition is checked after `a` is decreased.

Answer (score 2):

[for loop on cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for)

This is the definition of a `for` loop:

```
  for ( init_statement ; condition ; iteration_expression )
      statement;
```

> Executes *init_statement* once, then executes *statement* and *iteration_expression* repeatedly, until the value of *condition* becomes false. The test takes place before each iteration.

This is translated to the following steps:

1. `init_statement` is executed
2. `condition` is checked; if true goto step 3, if false goto step 6
3. execute `statement`
4. execute `iteration_expression`
5. goto step 2
6. the `for` loop is complete. (Skip `statement` and execute next statements)

In this case, the following steps are taken:

1. `a` is assigned `10` (a == 10)
2. `a >= 0` is checked, it is true
3. `10` is output to `cout`
4. `a -= 3` is executed (a == 7)
5. `a >= 0` is checked, it is true
6. `7` is output to `cout`
7. `a -= 3` is executed (a == 4)
8. `a >= 0` is checked, it is true
9. `4` is output to `cout`
10. `a -= 3` is executed (a == 1)
11. `a >= 0` is checked, it is true
12. `1` is output to `cout`
13. `a -= 3` is executed (a == -2)
14. `a >= 0` is checked, it is false
15. The `for` loop is complete. (Skip `statement` and execute next statements.)

Comment: yea that was what my original thinking was but then i kept over thinking things and still being quite fresh with C++ i forget everything i learned about '>=' from 5th grade math class... but really appreciate you taking the time with an in depth response like that. really helps to get a different perspective to see what i didn't so much appreciated there.